# How to set Authorization HTTP header when requesting JSONP?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, yelp

I'm trying to send a GET request to the Yelp API.

I'm getting a 401 error when I try with the code below. Based on my research, I don't think I can set the authorization in this way if I'm requesting JSONP data. However, I'm getting a Cross-Origin Request Blocked error when I try with another data type. How do I get around this issue?

```
function findFood() {
        var lat = document.getElementById("lat");
        var lon = document.getElementById("lon");

        console.log("lat: " + lat.textContent + " lon: " + lon.textContent);

        var url = API_HOST + SEARCH_PATH + "term=" + SEARCH_TERM + "&radius=" + SEARCH_RADIUS + "&latitude=" + parseFloat(lat.textContent) + "&longitude=" + parseFloat(lon.textContent);

        console.log(url);
        console.log("Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        })

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace the header by a POST data? On the Yelp website, that's what they said!
Check those links : [jQuery API Post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
& [Yelp API 2.0 Authentification](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/authentication) I really hope that this will work! Let me know in the comment section!

Comment: I'm trying to query the Yelp API for restaurants...Why would it be a POST call?

Comment: The problem is the authorization, your trying to log in Yelp API, but it doesn't work, so I'm just giving you an other way to do it! @stumpylumpy